# Integration of 'sort by' (and other filters) with SvelteKit

Tags: express, filtering, svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I have a backend route '/products' (using ExpressJS and Prisma) that returns a list of all products, however it also has some query parameters that can be used to specify futher, namely:

- page (and count): used for pagination
- sort and sortDir: used for sorting by a value in a specific direction (desc or asc)
- category: comma separated list of categories to search by

I load the products on the frontend SvelteKit project in `+page.server.ts` and display them in a table format. However, when the user changes, for instance, the sort direction, how would I update the page data using a new route (namely the original one, with sortDir=desc). Is there some way of [invalidating](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#invalidation) the query and replacing it with a new one, with the correct search parameters?

Or is there some other way that this is normally implemented in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using **searchParams** you can read the values in the load function:

```
// +page.server.js
export async function load({ fetch, url }) => {
  const sortDir = url.searchParams.get("sortDir")
  return {
    products: await ...,
  };
};
```

Accessing the searchParam will let SvelteKit know to invalidate and rerun/reload the page data when the parameter changes.

To change the searchParam use either regular urls: `<a href="?sortDir=asc">ASC</a>` or use the [goto](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) from the `$app/navigation` module.

PS. You don't need a separate express backend, you can access prisma directly from +page.server.js files.

Comment: Thanks! Will that append the search param onto the URL, or completely overwrite them? And I'll definitely look into Prisma on the +page.server.js files! That sounds useful :D

Comment: Overwrite them, so you might need to write a little utility function that generates urls based on the current searchParams. (Readable from the $page.url store)

Comment: Gotcha! Could it be worth storing them in a writable store, or is that overkill when I could simply parse the current url and modify it accordingly? (More of an opiniated question, I know, but just curious on your thoughts)